# Get all keys in MongoMapper Model including its association

Tags: mongodb, associations, mongomapper

Suppose the following model :

```
class Product 
 include MongoMapper::Document

 key :name, String
 key :product_category_id, ObjectId

 belongs_to :product_category
end

class ProductCategory
 include MongoMapper::Document

 key :name, String, :required => true, :unique => true

 timestamps!
 userstamps!
end
```

I want to implement an advanced search that will inspect all value inside my Model including its all association like :
I have :

- Product A data named "aLaptop" belongs_to:ProductCategory named "Notebook".
- Product B data named "aGreatNotebook" belongs_to:ProductCategory named "Notebook".

When I search with keyword named "Notebook", I want to search it to Product.name fields and also its associations which mean ProductCategory.name also. So it will returned both of that items, because Product A have ProductCategory.name "Notebook" & Product B have Product.name "aGreatNotebook" and ProductCategory "Notebook"..

How can I do this?? I've already searching for 2 days and not success until now:(.. When is in MySQL, I used join table.. But hows in MongoMapper??

Please help.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do joins in MongoDB. So the basic idea is to get the ObjectId associated with the "Notebook" category and then to query the products where product_category is equal to notebook_id. This generally involves two queries. So that'd be something like this:

```
notebook_id = ProductCategory.first(:name => "Notebook")
if notebook_id
  Product.where({:product_category_id => notebook_id['_id']})
end
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle Banker.. Thats exactly I was thinking, but how about if there is many association like 'Brands' in Product either than 'Product_Category'.. That means we must querying 3 times for each model to get its _ids ?? (1. Querying for ProductCategory._ids, Brand._ids, Product)..

Comment: Not really, you can use $in. ids = ProductCategory.where(:name => {:$in => ["Notebook", "Brands"]}). Unless I'm misunderstanding your question...

Comment: No, I mean 'Brands' is a another model, like 'Apple, Samsung, etc':).. And ProductCategoy is like 'Notebook, Printer, etc..'.. But both of them is associate with 'Product' model..

All I was thinking is how to get all keys of Product, ProductCategory, and Brand Model so I can search with only using single query :)..

Comment: If this information resides in more than one collection, then there's no way to do this in a single query (although MongoMapper's API might make it appear that way).

Comment: Hmm, okey then.. Thank you Kyle for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is confusing, but the title of the question is clear.

So in case someone comes here hoping to see how to get all of the:

- keys
- associations

Read on...

To get the keys in a model:

```
ConfinedSpace.keys.keys
 => ["_id", "photo_ids", "include_in_qap", "position", "created_at", "updated_at",
     "structure_id", "identifier", "name", "description", "notes", "entry_info", 
     "anchor_points", "nature", "special_equipment", "rescue_overview"]
```

And to get the associations:

```
ConfinedSpace.associations.each{|name,assoc| puts name}
photos
attachments
activities
structure
videos
```

And the class (edited for brevity):

```
class ConfinedSpace
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  include Shared::HasPhotos
  include Shared::HasAttachments
  include HasActivities

  TAG = "ConfinedSpace"

  belongs_to :structure
  many :videos, :as => :attachable

  key :identifier, String
  key :name, String
  key :description, String
  key :notes, String
  key :entry_info, String
  key :anchor_points, String
  key :nature, String
  key :special_equipment, String
  key :rescue_overview, String

  validates :identifier, presence: true

end
```